# Is overriding threading join dangerous?

Tags: python, multithreading, join

I have a thread, that does some stuff, in an infinite loop. Now I want to make sure, that everything is cleaned up properly, if I exit with cntrl-C. The solutions I found online seemed kind of complicated, and now I came up with the following solution, which seems to work fine:

```
import threading
import time

class Logger(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.shutdown = False
    
    def run(self):
        while not self.shutdown:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("I am busy")
        self.cleanup()
    
    def cleanup(self):
        print("cleaning up")
    
    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.shutdown = True
        return super().join(timeout=timeout)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_logger = Logger()
    my_logger.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Outside loop")
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        my_logger.join()
```

But since I have not found a similar implementation online, I was wondering: am I doing something dangerous? Especially overriding the Thread.join() method?

Comment: Typically, one would make `Logger` a context manager (by defining `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and use the logger in a `with` statement so that the cleanup code will be executed no matter how the `with` statement is exited.

Comment: Does this work with threading? So I would implement __enter__ and __exit__ in above class? How would the exiting work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is particularly bad, but it is odd. Note that in particular `join` can be called multiple times so you want things to be idempotent. Furthermore, if a `join` is used with timeout then it might be that it is not even *expected* that the thread would exit.

In any case, have you considered using two methods, one that triggers the shutdown after which you can use `join` and not have to worry about the effects of overriding?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You mean a seperate method, that sets self.shutdown = True? In that case I could also just do it this way:
```
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    my_logger.shutdown = True
    my_logger.join()
```
I would be just concerned, that in that case I would forget to set shutdown to True first.

Answer (score 1):

Not dangerous per se, but maybe confounding to some other programmer who is trying to read and understand your code. When they see the `join()` call, they won't be expecting it to do anything more than what the stock `join` method does.

It's maybe not a big deal here, but on a large project where there are many developers, I would challenge it during code review. I would ask "why can't the caller *explicitly* ask the `Logger` thread to shut down before `join`ing it?"

---

P.S., You might ask, If I don't like overriding a method to do more than what the base class method does, then what even is the point of using inheritance?

Well, I don't know. I almost never use it. I personally think that "has a" is a more powerful/more versatile relationship than "is a." E.g., if you asked me to write a `Logger`, my `Logger` would *have* a thread. It would not *be* a thread.